# Can not display the data in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

when i try to program my snmp then apply to the CodeIgniter framework, I can not display it

```html
this is my code
<?php foreach($monitor as $mnt){ ?>
<?php 
 // Set Variables:
 mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die (mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("monitor") or die (mysql_error());
 $hasil = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM device") or die (mysl_error());
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($hasil);
// Clean output function - Removes the extras given by SNMP
function clean_output($string) {
    $clean_output = preg_replace("/[A-Za-z]*:[ ]/", "", $string);
    $clean_output = preg_replace("/[(][0-9]*[)][ ]/", "", $clean_output);
    $clean_output = str_replace("Gauge32", "", $clean_output);
    $clean_output = str_replace("Counter32", "", $clean_output);
    $clean_output = preg_replace("/[(][0-9][)]/", "", $clean_output);
    return $clean_output;
}
 
// Create specific OIDs

$sysUptime = "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0";

# Check that we are able to contact the system, If we are then run the rest of the SNMP gets.
$oo8 = clean_output(snmpget($row['host'],$row['comm'],$sysUptime));
 
if($oo8 != "") { 
    // Now we know that we can contact the device, run the other SNMP gets.
    
 $oo8 = clean_output(snmpget($row['host'],$row['comm'],$sysUptime));
 
    }
 
// Show the System stats at the start of the table.

echo "<center><br><b>Uptime:</b></br></center><center> $oo8</center>";

?>
<?php } ?>
```

The contents of a folder in the controller

```html
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class home extends CI_Controller {

 public function index()
 {
 $comp = array(
 "header" => $this->load->view("header",array(),true),
 "monitor" => $this->html_monitor(),
 );
  $this->load->view("index",$comp);
 }
 public function html_monitor(){
 $data = array(
 "device" => $this->mymodel->GetDevice(),
 );
 return $this->load->view("monitor",$data,true);
}
}
```

Comment: Please read about why you [shouldn't be using `mysql_*` functions anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: Where do you define `$monitor`?

Comment: I define $ monitor in controller